# jQuery datatable throwing error when foreach loop loading data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
> at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:24)

from my code shown below. I don't see any fault in my code. when iterating dictionary values it is throwing the error. If I comment `foreach` loop, the datatable is loading properly with headers. What could be the problem?

```
<table class="dataTableWrapper" id="dynamic_table_container" data-target="#categories">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>COUNTRY</th>
            <th>CATEGORY</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var country in countrieslstAndPriceGroup)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@country.Key</td>
                <td>@country.Value</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table> 

<script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        var t = $('#dynamic_table_container').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 25,
            "columnDefs": [
                { // set default column settings
                    "orderable": false,
                    "targets": [1, 2, 4]
                }
            ],
            "bFilter": false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `[1, 2, 4]` How many columns do you have?

Comment: only 2 columns .

Comment: `4` is the fifth column. Yet you have only 2 columns?

Comment: ` "targets": [1, 2]` is enough for 2 columns?

Comment: Try `[0,1]` or `[1,2]`.

Comment: targets are by index not count so [0,1] would be correct